# Doing a GQL query with java?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

While working with datastore I saw that all the queries in the datastore are parsed in the format `SELECT * FROM kind WHERE property = someValue`. I was working with Android Studio and while debugging I saw it. Also you can run this type of query on the app server.

Later I came to learn that it was called `GQL`. I searched stackoverflow for proper implementation but in every post I found that `GQL queries` on Java is not supported. However, it can be done via 3rd party tools. So I looked at official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql).

Now here I saw a code snippet in Java. But when i tried to implement it, it does not work. I mean the code does not even compile let alone work. There are compilation errors.

Even the line 
`import static com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.client.DatastoreHelper.*;`
which you will find on protocol buffers in Java Section does not work.

Now is the official documentation faulty? Or I am making a mistake?

I am looking for a simple implementation on GQL queries on java and so far I have not found any solution. I am using Android Studio.

I know about datastore queries and implemented them with Android Studio. I am NOT looking for any alternatives for GQL queries. If anyone has any working solution on GQL queries on java, please help.

Comment: I think it may be that documentation you are looking at is about writing Java programs that query the datastore, rather then Java programs running on Google-App-Engine that query the datastore. As if you look here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_query_interface you can see a very similar setup for appengine Java queries that is *not* GQL.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gql4j/

Comment: Paul Collingwood, I dont understand. what's the difference?

Peter Knego, I did mention there was third party tools available. i saw gql4j. But i want to know why the official documentation do not work?

Comment: GQL it looks like is supported by the datastore REST API [1] which would be why non-GAE Java apps (or any language) would work with it via 3rd party tools. The datastore on GAE uses its own low-level API (as per Paul's link) which doesn't provide any GQL-enabled methods. [1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery

Comment: You ever have any luck figuring this out? I keep getting The import com.google.apphosting.client.datastoreservice.client cannot be resolved myself and cannot get a query to work...